# Reference external file with ^ in name

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to pull data from external workbooks into a main workbook.  I have done this before several times and it always works with the below formula.

```
='FolderPath[FileName]WorksheetName'!CellReference
```

The above formula still works for me now on many workbooks.  However I have thousands of workbooks with a `^` in the name.  Example `Workbook1^01012017`.
When I get to these types of workbooks I get the below error:

`"The syntax of this name isn't correct."` and the text in the cell gets highlighted until the first `^`.

1. If I type in = in my original workbook
2. Open the workbook I want to reference
3. Select the cell I need
4. Hit Enter

The link works.  If I copy that text exactly and change the reference from cell A1 to A2 in another cell, I get the same error.  The problem seems to be that it's reading the ^ as a symbol instead of a text.  Is there any other way to get this to work?  I have tried using a indirect function, but those don't work when the external workbook is closed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The text in what cell gets highlited? Provide a [minimal version](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code that we can try.

Comment: What's the VBA involvement here?

Comment: @TimWilliams , I am using Excel 2016 in windows 10.

Comment: @DavidG I provided the formula at the very beginning. ='FolderPath[FileName]WorksheetName'!CellReference  From "='FolderPath[FileName]" until the ^ in filename gets highlighted.  so if the path is ='\\somedrive\somefolder\[Workbook^123] everything before the ^ would be highlighted.

Comment: So there's no VBA involved here?  Why the tags?

Comment: I am doing this in VBA but the VBA code is just cell.formula = "the code above"  But I am trying to get this to work outside of VBA through excels formula bar.  Once I get that working then I can put it back into my VBA code.

Comment: you could use FileSystemObject and rename all the files with the '^' character
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711216(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Jason_Walker we were trying to keep all of the files the same name.  I changed my code to just loop through the workbooks and open them to pull the data in.  Even though that works, I would still be interested in how to do this.  I don't really understand why the character makes a difference.

Comment: `selection.formula = "='C:\Users\namHere\Desktop\[temp^file.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1"` works fine for me.

Comment: @VBA_SQL_Programmer I tried to test it by creating a file '1^.xlsx' and doing an equals range A1 from this file in another workbook.  I am unable to repeat the error

Comment: Okay thanks guys.  I don't know what it could be then.  For me when I create a new file without a ^ mark it reads the value just fine.  When I do it with a ^ it fails.

Comment: Are the files on a local drive, or do they use a network/UNC path ?

Comment: I can create this formula error if I use the `‘` and `’` characters (the distinct left and right single quotes that you would get in Word, for example) instead of the normal single quote - `'`